# what is the scope of $_ in a foreach-object loop in Powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach-object

Here's a simplified version of the script I'm trying to write:

```
$i = 0
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.bat|
ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_.Name
    switch ($i) {
        0 { Write-Host $_.Name}
        1 { Write-Host $_.Name }
        2 { Write-Host $_.Name }
        Default {Write-Host "nothing here"}
    }
}
```

So the first `Write-Host` command works as expected, but once I get inside the switch statement `Write-Host` prints out nothing, which is mystifying to me. I assume the problem has something to do with the scope of `$_` but I don't know. I'm a total Powershell amateur. Isn't the switch statement inside the foreach loop so the scope shouldn't be an issue?

If I do this then everything works like I expected, the filenames get printed from inside and outside the switch statement:

```
$i = 0
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.bat |
ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_.Name
    $temp = $_.Name
    switch ($i) {
        0 { Write-Host $temp }
        1 { Write-Host $temp }
        2 { Write-Host $temp }
        Default {Write-Host "nothing here"}
    }
}
```

Can someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: In addition to the information provided in the answers, I commend to your attention [Microsoft Learn on Scopes in Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_` is getting a different value inside your `switch` statement - it's actually getting the value of `$i` and it therefore is an `Int32` and doesn't have a `Name` property. When you assign to `$temp` and use that inside the switch it works because you assign the (string) value you want to a new variable.

If you were to use `$_` again *after* the switch you would be able to access all the properties as before.

By using the code below, you're able to see what type `$_` is taking as it is used in the different scopes/pipelines

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.bat |
ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_.gettype()
    switch ($i) {
        Default {
          Write-Host $_.gettype()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so $_ is the pipe variable and because the switch statement gets $i as input, $i becomes the new pipe variable until the switch is over?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: I see my mistake was not considering that $_ could have other uses. In the documentation it only says use the $_ variable to access the current object. It would be helpful for self taught amateurs like me if it mentioned something about $_ possibly being overwritten by other things. And so this isn't a scope issue after all

Answer (score 3):

As written here:

[about_Switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.3)

The thing is that The $_ automatic variable contains the value of the expression passed to the switch statement.
That means that it does not contain the same value as it had before you entered into the switch statement.

Move over, if you would like to read more about $_ you can also refer to this article:

[What Does $_ Mean in PowerShell](https://linuxhint.com/dollar-underscore-mean-in-powershell/)

Good luck :)